# Swift: Pass an AVaudioplayer name as a string

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

Reasonably new to Swift and I'm trying to pass the name of my AVaudioplayer to a function to play a sound with that player.

```
 var playname=sender.accessibilityLabel!; (this is the name of the AVaudioplayer)
```

> playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabelB!, bgp: playname) - Cannot
> convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type
> 'AVAudioPlayer?'

Obviously, I need to know how to pass the string as the actual name of the player.

Player functions starts like:

```
func playbg(bgtrack:String,bgp: inout AVAudioPlayer?){ 

... }
```

Below is the only way I can get it to work, which means the more sounds added the more crazy the code becomes. I was able to do all this with one line in Javascript...

```
if (playname=="bgcar"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &bgcar)}
if (playname=="bgrain"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &bgrain)}
if (playname=="bgtent"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &bgtent)}
if (playname=="bgtrain"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &bgtrain)}
if (playname=="city"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &city)}
if (playname=="crickets"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &crickets)}
if (playname=="fan"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &fan)}
if (playname=="fire"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &fire)}
if (playname=="hoover"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &hoover)}
if (playname=="plane"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &plane)}
if (playname=="roof"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &roof)}
if (playname=="sea"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &sea)}
if (playname=="storm"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &storm)}
if (playname=="underwater"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &underwater)}
if (playname=="water"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &water)}
if (playname=="wind"){playbg(bgtrack: sender.accessibilityLabel!, bgp: &wind)}
```

This is the first time I've asked something here... please be kind stackoverflow ;)

Comment: (1) Why does this object need a name? (2) Why are you trying to pass a string (the name) where an actual AVAudioPlayer is expected?

Comment: Because there are multiple players for certain events which require exact control. It needs to know the player it is using.

Comment: But you don't need an extra property (a string name) in order to know which of the players this is. You can just use a `switch` (with the `===` operator). Have you got a better reason? In general objects do not need names, because they already have unique identity; using names is almost always a Bad Smell.

Comment: From the tenor of your question, it looks like you are fairly new to programming, not just to Swift.  Is `playbg` something you're written yourself, or is it a fuction that someone else has created for you?

Comment: I've added to the question the only way I can get the player name to be passed. I am converting from javascript to swift. In javascript it was just one line to pass the player name from a string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are struggling with a lot of things all at once.

Let's start with some high-level programming knowledge.  One of the main jobs of a person writing code is to create a model of the problem.  In this case the problem you are trying to model seems to have something to do with playing a bunch of sounds.  The model that the JavaScript folks came up with appears to involve some kind of string that lets you identify the sound you want to play (perhaps?  not really enough detail here).

The folks that created a model that Swift is probably different.  It looks like you are still trying to use JavaScript's models even though you've switched languages and operating environments.

Just off hand it looks like you are trying to use a different `AVAudioPlayer` for each sound.  I can't claim to be an expert in `AVAudioPlayers` but I suspect that you are supposed to create one and then pass various sounds to it to be played when needed.

The `accessibilityLabel` is not for you, the programmer, to use to identify the audio source. It is designed so that the object holds a name that will be meaningful to folks using you application. You shouldn't be using it in the way you seem to want to.

Finally your long chain of `if` statements is a problem that programmers in early languages ran into as well. They created a special language structure, the `switch` statement to simplify that logical flow.

I think what you are working with here is what is called [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Perhaps if you gave us some more information about what you are doing in JavaScript and the community could help you how to do the same thing through the Apple SDKs with Swift.